# Фильтрация списка через api/php

Tags: php

Всем привет, сделал подключение по api при подключении подучил код ответа 200 и список: [image: Список]
Теперь мне нужно сделать фильтр по запросу городов и выдачи отелей в них и как это реализовать, кто сможет подсказать ?

Вот код подключение от того что на скриншоте:

```
$login = '****';
$password = '**********';
$authCode = base64_encode($login . ':' . $password);
$opts = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => 'GET',
        'header' => 'Authorization: Basic ' . $authCode
    )
);
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
// Открываем файл с помощью установленных выше HTTP-заголовков
$file = file_get_contents('https://partner.ostrovok.ru/api/affiliate/v2/region/list?data={"land":"ru"}', false, $context);
print $file;
```

Comment: `json_decode($file);` и у вас получается замечательная структура. Дальше ищите что вам нужно

Comment: Не совсем понял

Comment: Что же тут может быть "не совсем понятного"? RTFM [json_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php). Скорректируйте последнюю строчку своего скрипта - напишите вместо `print $file` команды `$data=json_decode($file); echo '<pre>'; var_dump($data); echo '</pre>';`. Выполните код и полюбуйтесь на красиво выведенную структуру данных. После этого решайте, что, где и как в ней Вы будете искать.

Comment: Документация их API https://partner.ostrovok.ru/wiki/apiv2/hotel_availability